# Convert from byte array to string hex c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, byte

Suppose I have byte array.

```
byte[] a = new byte[] {0x33,0x43,0xFE};
```

I want to convert it to `string`.

```
 string str = convert(a);
```

My str should look like this:

```
"33 43 FE"
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

use bitconverter class

```
 BitConverter.ToString(Bytes);
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use this code:

```
byte[] a = new byte[] { 0x33, 0x43, 0xFE };
string str = string.Join(" ", a.Select(b => string.Format("{0:X2} ", b)));
```

so the `convert` method could be

```
string convert(byte [] a)
{
    return string.Join(" ", a.Select(b => string.Format("{0:X2} ", b)));
}
```

The `X2` is used in order to get each byte represented with two uppercase hex digits, if you want one digit only for numbers smaller than 16 like `0xA` for example, use `{0:X}` and if you want lowercase digits use `{0:x}` format.